# What is cuEventRecord guaranteed to do if it gets the default-stream's handle?

Tags: cuda-streams, cuda-driver, cuda-events

Suppose I call `cuEventRecord(0, my_event_handle)`.

`cuEventRecord()` requires the stream and the event to belong to the same context. Now, one can interpret the `0` as "the default stream in the appropriate context" - the requirements are satisfied and this should work; but one can also interpret it as "the default stream in the current context" - in which case if the current context is not the event's context - this should fail. Or it may all just be undefined/inconsistent behavior.

My question: Is `cuEventRecord()` guaranteed to prefer one interpretation over the other?

Answer (score 0):

My personal tinkering suggests that the CUDA driver expects the *current* context to be the event and the stream's context. Perhaps it even expects that for *any* stream, not just the default one. Try this program:

```c++
#include <cuda/api.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
    cuda::initialize_driver();
    auto pc_0 = cuda::device::primary_context::detail_::obtain_and_increase_refcount(0);
    auto pc_1 = cuda::device::primary_context::detail_::obtain_and_increase_refcount(1);
    cuda::context::current::detail_::push(pc_1);
    CUevent eh = cuda::event::detail_::create_raw_in_current_context(0);
    cuda::context::current::pop();
    // At this point, the context stack is empty
    cuda::context::current::detail_::push(pc_0);
    CUstream default_stream_handle = nullptr;
    cuda::event::detail_::enqueue_in_current_context(default_stream_handle, eh);
}
```

with [this commit](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/tree/3a037bb3d54e1b4bc6489aaef28bdb74da961620) of my [cuda-api-wrappers](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-api-wrappers/) library to see for yourself; if you replace `pc_0` with `pc_1` - it all works.